# Fastest way to swap sections between two ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists.

Content of List 1 is:

> 1,2,**3,4,5**,6,7

Content of List 2 is:

> 7,6,**5,4,3**,2,1

Now I want to swap the bold sections of the two ArrayLists.

Comment: I accidently hit the Submit button. For now I swap these sections by creating two new ArrayLists and using the old lists as constructor. Then I use a for-loop and do newlist1.set(i,list2.get(i)). I'm pretty sure this is the slowest way to swap. What can I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a loop.

```
 public static <T> void swap(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, int from, int to) {
      for(int i = from; i < to; i++) 
           list2.set(i, list1.set(i, list2.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: Neat and precise answer :)

Comment: The set/set/get trick is a bit obscure, but hopefully understandable.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely understandable!

Answer (score 1):

If the contents doesn't change then you can directly use

```
 Collections.reverse(list1.subList(2,5));
 Collections.reverse(list2.subList(2,5));
```

Comment: Nice trick, this doesn't swap them, but the result is equivalent for the example in the question :)

Comment: @Katona yes it does't swap them :)